# EntityFramework CF strange behavior at editing entity

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

Sorry for my bad English.
I have EF 6 codefirst models for database.
3 models is usually static, loaded at program startup (using aka foreign keys for last table).
Last model is dynamical - data is loaded too, stored in c# collection, but user can add, edit rows and save added/edited to DB.
For 3 first models i have checkboxes with *selecteditem* binding.
User can edit last table model entity, select items from checkboxes and save to DB.
This is simple and standart solution.

Partial models without trash fields (to reference from last table).

```
    [Table("Users")]
public partial class User
{
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int ClientId { get; set; }
    [StringLength(160)]
    public string ClientName { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Repair> Repairs { get; set; }
    public User()
    {
        Repairs = new List<Repair>();
    }
}
  [Table("RepairStatuses")]
public partial class RepairStatus
{
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [StringLength(10)]
    public string Status { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Repair> Repairs { get; set; }
    public RepairStatus()
    {
        Repairs = new List<Repair>();
    }
}
    [Table("CurrentStatuses")]
public partial class CurrentStatus
{
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int StatusId { get; set; }
    [StringLength(10)]
    public string Status { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Repair> Repairs { get; set; }
    public CurrentStatus()
    {
        Repairs = new List<Repair>();
    }
}
```

And main editable table model (partial too w/o trash fields).

```
    [Table("Repairs")]
public partial class Repair
{
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Column(TypeName = "date")]
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    [StringLength(255)]
    public string HardwareInfo { get; set; }
    public virtual User User { get; set; }
    public virtual RepairStatus RepairStatus { get; set; }
    public virtual CurrentStatus CurrentStatus { get; set; }
}
```

In my *AddEntity* method all working (attach unchanged items from combobox to DbContext, add new row, save changes). *Eager loading.*

```
  using (ServiceDBContext cntx = new ServiceDBContext())
       {
          cntx.Users.Attach(SelectedRepair.User);
          cntx.CurrentStatuses.Attach(SelectedRepair.CurrentStatus);
          cntx.RepairStatuses.Attach(SelectedRepair.RepairStatus);
          cntx.Entry(SelectedRepair.RepairStatus).State = EntityState.Modified;
          cntx.Entry(SelectedRepair.CurrentStatus).State = EntityState.Modified;
          cntx.Entry(SelectedRepair.User).State = EntityState.Modified;
          cntx.Repairs.Attach(SelectedRepair);
          cntx.Entry(SelectedRepair).State = EntityState.Added;
   ...
          cntx.SaveChanges();
   ...
```

But with *EditEntity* method i have strange behavior (sorry for stupid code...)

```
   using (ServiceDBContext wrk = new ServiceDBContext())
      {
       var tmp = (((((wrk.Repairs.Where(x => x.Id ==SelectedRepair.Id)).Include(y => y.CurrentStatus)).Include(y => y.RepairStatus)).Include(y => y.Engineer)).Include(y => y.User)).FirstOrDefault();
   if (tmp.User.ClientId != SelectedRepair.User.ClientId)
       {
          tmp.User = SelectedRepair.User;
          wrk.Users.Attach(tmp.User);
          wrk.Entry(tmp.User).State = EntityState.Modified;
       }
    if (tmp.RepairStatus.Id != SelectedRepair.RepairStatus.Id)
       {
          tmp.RepairStatus = SelectedRepair.RepairStatus;
          wrk.RepairStatuses.Attach(tmp.RepairStatus);
          wrk.Entry(tmp.RepairStatus).State = EntityState.Modified;
       }
    if (tmp.CurrentStatus.StatusId != SelectedRepair.CurrentStatus.StatusId)
       {
          tmp.CurrentStatus = SelectedRepair.CurrentStatus;
          wrk.CurrentStatuses.Attach(tmp.CurrentStatus);
          wrk.Entry(tmp.CurrentStatus).State = EntityState.Modified;
       }
     ...
     wrk.Entry(tmp).State = EntityState.Modified;
     wrk.SaveChanges();
     }
```

For example: *CurrentStatuses* table have 2 entities ("1. OK", "2. Bad").
Then user first time changing in *Repair* table in selected row CurrentStatus foreign key (for example, with id =1 to foreign key with id=2) all is OK.
In VS debugger i can see...

```
UPDATE [dbo].[CurrentStatuses] SET [Status] = @0 WHERE ([StatusId] = @1)
UPDATE [dbo].[Repairs] SET ... WHERE (([Id] = @12) AND ([CurrentStatus_StatusId] = @13))
```

If user want to change second time this entity **from id=2 to id=1** (reverse) its throwing error "An error occurred while saving entities that do not expose foreign key properties for their relationships..."

**AND in debugger we can see some magic with "Reader (INSERT)" attempts to all database relative tables o_O and attempt to INSERT in *Repair* table dublicate entry (which was been selected to edit).**

One INSERT example (Repair, RepairStatus and User have like this INSERTS too):

```
DECLARE @0 AS SQL_VARIANT;
SET @0 = NULL;
INSERT [dbo].[CurrentStatuses]([Status])
VALUES (@0)
SELECT [StatusId]
FROM [dbo].[CurrentStatuses]
WHERE @@ROWCOUNT > 0 AND [StatusId] = scope_identity()
```

After program restart we can change CurrentStatus foreign key **from id=2 to id=1** normally (but only 1 time too).
Can someone help me to solve this problem?
Thanks!

Comment: Why do you keep reattaching `tmp.CurrentStatus`, `tmp.RepairStatus` in your code when they belong to detached entity `SelectedRepair`? You should reload them through DB, otherwise you can expect EF freaking out when you do something unexpected.

Comment: I know that this table entity already in database. And i have it in memory already. Noone can change this object. I think that entity haven't any problem... oO Or not?

Comment: It tries to insert an entity CurrentStatus with Status = NULL to your database, so it seems that entity is somehow referenced by change tracker somewhere, you should check this. Overall code with attach/detach and ChangeTracker is very hard to support and search for issues like that.

Comment: I don't understand you =/ Repair entity was loaded from Repairs table, i change some data in this entity... Entity Framework used to speed up development, but I have regretted many times about choise of this dll. Strange bugs, behaviors... raderick, thank you...